# Client-Server Communication (without port forwarding) when both are behind routers

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

hi 
I have a client and server both of which are behind routers. They need to communicate over sockets. Enabling port-forwarding is not an option.
The client-server will maintain a live socket connection and the server will notify the client when an event occurs. Polling as an alternative for the client is not an option.
I am using plain-java.
How do I go about doing this?

Regards
Chimanrao

Comment: If both the client and the server are behind routers, and port forwarding is not an option, then they cannot possibly find each other. You will have to forward _some_ port to the server.

Comment: UPNP? Or STUN with a man-in-the-middle server? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal

Comment: Also, on June 8 we going to have World IPv6 Day. IPv6 is another option, unfortunately, likely years ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use UPnP. That is about the only option if you do not have a server outside of the NAT.

Comment: +1. There are another option too (skype uses it) and that's that a third client which is not behind a router acts as a server.